# Using post-content returns '0'

Tags: php, wordpress

When I'm trying to utilise the post functions of Wordpress on another page, something odd happens.

I'm attempting to grab a specific post using the predefined ID of the Wordpress post and the title, content and date within it using the code as follows:

```
$post = get_post( $_GET['p'] );
echo "<hr><h1>" . $post->post_title . "<br /></h1>";
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post-content ) . "<br /><br />";
echo "Published on: " . $post->post_date;
```

However this produces the following output:

[image: word press]

When the 0 should be replaced by a lot of lopus ipsum text.

I've had a look around the Wordpress support sites and Google to no avail, any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `post_content` not `post-content` :)

Comment: And this is when I feel like an idiot... last time I copy snippits directly over from webpages.

Comment: Don't sweat it.  I spent a good 10 minutes yesterday scratching my head wondering why my PHP wasn't working as expected before I realized it was because I was using the JS concatenation operator